# Google Glass Voice Recognition

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-glass, google-gdk

What I tried to do:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

ArrayList<String> voiceResults = getIntent().getExtras()
.getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

Card ShowDataCard = new Card(this);
ShowDataCard.setText(voiceResults);
View ShowDataCardView = ShowDataCard.toView();
setContentView(ShowDataCardView);
}
```

Failed work-around:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String voiceResults = getIntent().getExtras()
            .getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

    Card ShowDataCard = new Card(this);
    ShowDataCard.setText(voiceResults);
    View ShowDataCardView = ShowDataCard.toView();
    setContentView(ShowDataCardView);
}
```

The String voiceResults is a failed workaround to the fact I cannot .setText to an arraylist string

Actual voice recognition code:

```
ArrayList<String> voiceResults = getIntent().getExtras()
    .getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

Basically I am trying to save this voice recognition (going to use SharedPreferences) but for some reason it is an arraylist string and not just a string. Anybody know how to save it as a String? (or publish an activity with an arraylist string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the results are an `ArrayList` of strings, you should check that the `size()` of the list is at least 1 and then call `voiceResults.get(0)` to get the string.

Comment: Wow that makes total sense. Will try when I get home